# Wordpress Magento problems infinate loop redirect problems

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento

Major problems with our wordpress and Magento sites. Our wordpress site is at webroot /public_html. It is creating a default .htaccess file because of the permalinks.

Our magento site sits at /public_html/store.

Everything is fine in Chrome, Firefox is complaining of a redirect loop and IE refuses to load anything at all.

We are paying a lot of money to adwords and we are worried that this is affecting our audience.

Any Ideas please?

Comment: Where is the redirect loop taking place?

Comment: It shows in Firefox, Chrome loads fine and IE just gives a 'Hmm, we can't reach this page' error. 

the site is www.lynxpolythene.com and the store is www.lynxpolythene.com/store.

Comment: post your `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

## tawk.to app 302 redirect

You have a 302 page found endless loop. It's being triggered by the Tawk.to app. Disable the app or plugin and test.

Comment: Brilliant - that worked a treat, I have put in a tawkto plugin in the wordpress site and also try a different method of entering the tawkto script in magento. Thank You so much!! I will check tonight from another location and browser, but its looking good so far.

Comment: no still problems from another location with firefox and IE. same errors.

I also thought it could be a fault with Cloudflare so i have moved NS back to original, this hasn't helped either.